# How to replace text between parentheses in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a dictionary containing the following key-value pairs: d={'Alice':'x','Bob':'y','Chloe':'z'}

I want to replace the lower case variables(values) by the constants(keys) in any given string.

For example, if my string is:

> A(x)B(y)C(x,z)

how do I replace the characters in order to get a resultant string of :

> A(Alice)B(Bob)C(Alice,Chloe)

Should I use regular expressions?

Comment: didn't got you give ur input and output in a proper way

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: Yes, generally a regular expression is a good solution to this type of problem. You'll likely want a "capture group", but `re.findall` may also become a valid solution.

Comment: This is my desired output.   A(Alice)B(Bob)C(Alice,Chloe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`re.sub()` solution with *replacement* function:

```
import re

d = {'Alice':'x','Bob':'y','Chloe':'z'}
flipped = dict(zip(d.values(), d.keys()))
s = 'A(x)B(y)C(x,z)'
result = re.sub(r'\([^()]+\)', lambda m: '({})'.format(','.join(flipped.get(k,'')
                                      for k in m.group().strip('()').split(','))), s)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
A(Alice)B(Bob)C(Alice,Chloe)
```

---

Extended version:

```
import re

def repl(m):
    val = m.group().strip('()')
    d = {'Alice':'x','Bob':'y','Chloe':'z'}
    flipped = dict(zip(d.values(), d.keys()))
    if ',' in val:
        return '({})'.format(','.join(flipped.get(k,'') for k in val.split(',')))
    else:
        return '({})'.format(flipped.get(val,''))


s = 'A(x)B(y)C(x,z)'
result = re.sub(r'\([^()]+\)', repl, s)

print(result)
```

---

*Bonus* approach for particular input case `A(x)B(y)C(Alice,z)`:

```
...
s = 'A(x)B(y)C(Alice,z)'
result = re.sub(r'\([^()]+\)', lambda m: '({})'.format(','.join(flipped.get(k,'') or k
                                      for k in m.group().strip('()').split(','))), s)

print(result)
```

Comment: @GayathriRavi: Then upvote/accept it as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: How do I modify the code if my input is A(x)B(y)C(Alice,z) and require the output : A(Alice)B(Bob)C(Alice,Chloe) ?

Comment: @GayathriRavi, if there's an additional case - it should be mentioned in the initial question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry about that. Can you help me out? I'm stuck with this.

Comment: @GayathriRavi, see my bonus approach

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to replace the values in a string with the respective keys of the dictionary. If my assumption is correct you can try this without using regex.

First the swap the keys and values using dictionary comprehension.

```
my_dict = {'Alice':'x','Bob':'y','Chloe':'z'}
my_dict = { y:x for x,y in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

Then using list_comprehension, you replace the values

```
str_ = 'A(x)B(y)C(x,z)'
output = ''.join([i if i not in my_dict.keys() else my_dict[i]  for i in str_])
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you need ;)

**Code**

```
import re

d={'Alice':'x','Bob':'y','Chloe':'z'}
keys = d.keys()
values = d.values()

s = "A(x)B(y)C(x,z)"
for i in range(0, len(d.keys())):
    rx = r"" + re.escape(values[i])
    s = re.sub(rx, keys[i], s)  

print s
```

**Output**

```
A(Alice)B(Bob)C(Alice,Chloe)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way that I would do it:

```
import re

def sub_args(text, tosub):
    ops = '|'.join(tosub.keys())

    for argstr, _ in re.findall(r'(\(([%s]+?,?)+\))' % ops, text):

        args = argstr[1:-1].split(',')
        args = [tosub[a] for a in args]
        subbed = '(%s)' % ','.join(map(str, args))
        text = re.sub(re.escape(argstr), subbed, text)

    return text

text = 'A(x)B(y)C(x,z)'
tosub = {
    'x': 'Alice',
    'y': 'Bob',
    'z': 'Chloe'
}

print(sub_args(text, tosub))
```

Basically you just use the regex pattern to find all of the argument groups and substitute in the proper values--the nice thing about this approach is that you don't have to worry about subbing where you don't want to (for example, if you had a string like 'Fn(F,n)'). You can also have multi-character keys, like 'F(arg1,arg2)'.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use the replace method in python like this:

```
d={'x':'Alice','y':'Bob','z':'Chloe'}

str = "A(x)B(y)C(x,z)"
for key in d:
  str = str.replace(key,d[key])
print (str)
```

But yeah you should swipe your dictionary values like Kishore suggested.

Comment: Great! Thank you